# Remove parentheses from the output of the selection command in the Postgrades database

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to use the select command in the Postgress database.
I use the following command to select.
But there is a parenthesis in the output.
What command should I use so that there is no parentheses in the output?

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
p = " select price from mobile "
cursor.execute(p)
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

[(1300.0,), (1100.0,), (1200.0,), (1100.0,), (1200.0,), (1500.0,)]

Comment: That query returns a two-dimensional Python array with one column (price) and several rows.  When you use `print` on that array, it uses Python's two-dimensional array syntax, which is what you see here.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to see the prices.
Such as: [1300.0, 1100.0,1200.0, 1100.0, 1200.0,1500.0]

What should I do?

Comment: Write some sort of list-comprehension or loop code to `print()` the prices one by one. With respect, explaining how to handle arrays and lists is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow answers. That's fundamental programming knowledge you can pick up from a tutorial.

Comment: @o.jones if you want to be snippy, I could point out that it's a list not an array, and specifically it's a list of tuples, not a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Take the first item from each row, and store those items in a new list.  (A list of values, rather than a list of rows.)

```
result_1d = [row[0] for row in result]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot MatBailie